# JSon and objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I want to use the JSon library in my iPhone project, and went to this site:
[JSON](http://www.json.org/)

And there I choosed the Cocoa JSON Framework, but the site don't want to load for me. Any ideas how to fix this problem? Or suggestions for a place where I can get the JSon for objective-c?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/), on Google Code.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON). It is based on the CocoaJSON framework.

Answer (score 2):

a) In the text box on the top right on this page, type: "objective-c json library"

b) Hit return

c) Read [the results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objective-c+json+library)