# Which JSON library to use for data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

There appears to be at least three different libraries for extracting JSON data from an HTTP request.

- TouchJSON (http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/)
- BSJSONAdditions (listed at json.org - http://blakeseely.com/blog/archives/2006/03/29/bsjsonadditions-12/
- json-framework (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

Any reason I would select one of these over the other or all they all about the same, in terms of speed and least bugginess?

The data I'm dealing with will probably have some semi-complex JSON strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend TouchJSON.  It's worked well for me performance-wise and at the time seemed easier to set up than json-framework (although json-framework works just as well).  I have not used BSJSONAdditions.

Other related (or duplicate) questions: [JSon and objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914060/json-and-objective-c) and [Saving and Editing JSON on iPhone/iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895708/saving-and-editing-json-on-iphone-ipod)

Comment: I like his question better though.  I'm flagging those as a duplicate of this one!

Comment: I agree, this question is much better worded.  I guess I'll follow suit - just curious if this is proper SO etiquette?

Comment: I am the author of json-framework. Your assertion that it requires the installation of additional SDKs is false. (It did *allow* you to install it as an SDK if you liked that approach, but this was by no means required.)

Comment: Sorry to be spreading false rumors, in that case. I think I had just followed the installation instructions which used the SDK method. I've updated my response accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the json-framework right now, and have no complaints. I've also heard good things about TouchJSON.