# Reading JSON in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which JSON library to use for data on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977800/which-json-library-to-use-for-data-on-iphone)

I have a JSON file. I want to read each element value and store those values into an array.

How do i proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSJSONSerialization`. It's built in.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Provided you are targeting ios5 or newer versions though!